# Clustering a scheduled task on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: cluster-computing, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a two-node cluster running Windows Server 2008 R2.  It is essentially an active/passive cluster for SQL Server.

I have set up a scheduled task on the current active node.  I want to set up that same task on the passive node but have it so that the task only runs on the active node.

I realise that this version of Windows doesn't support clustered tasks, but I thought that a work-around might be to create another task that is triggered on the node becoming 'active' which enables the first task, and a partner task to disable the first task when the node becomes 'passive'.

I haven't found anything on the internet about doing something like this though, so I was wondering whether this was possible, and if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found a way to do this.

To enable or disable tasks from the command line I can use the schtasks command:

```
schtasks /Change /TN "MyTask" /ENABLE
schtasks /Change /TN "MyTask" /DISABLE
```

I can place these commands in a .bat file and trigger them to run when the cluster is activated by creating a task and setting a trigger with the following settings:

```
Begin the task: On an event
Log: Microsoft-Windows-FailoverClustering/Operational
Source: FailoverClustering
EventID: 1201
```

A similar task with EventID 1204 will trigger when the cluster is taken offline.

Combining all this means that I can create a task on both nodes of my cluster and only ever have it enabled on the active node.

One big caveat with this is that I haven't yet tested it!  I'm also not 100% certain that those events will always fire (if, for example, a node loses power and is subsequently rebooted) so I might also need to check for some other events.  It looks promising though.

Comment: Hello PaulH, I was wondering if you have now tested the solution you proposed? So you disabled your scheduled tasks when a node is being set to inactive and enable them in the node that is being activated. What evemts do you use for "Is Activating" and "Is Deactivating". Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I use generic script for enabling and disabling tasks:

```
WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
strEnableTask = "schtasks /change /ENABLE /TN \"\\Task\"";
strDisableTask = "schtasks /change /DISABLE /TN \"\\Task\"";

function Open() {
 return true;
}

function Online() {
 oExec = WshShell.Run(strEnableBackup, 0, true);
 return oExec.ExitCode;
}

function LooksAlive() {
 return true;
}

function IsAlive() {
 return true;
}

function Offline() {
 oExec = WshShell.Run(strDisableBackup, 0, true);
 return oExec.ExitCode;
}

function Close() {
 return true;
}

function Terminate() {
 return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @SeyfSV that script looks useful.  In relation to the original question though it doesn't explain how to run this script so that scheduled tasks are activated or deactivated based on the current state of the cluster node that they are set up on.

Comment: MS cluster has resource Generic Script. You can create resource in Resource Group that control you database, for example, and attach this script to it, and now, when resource (Resource Group) comes online it will enable schedule, offline - disable.